# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. while trying to simulate onChange event

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate an onChange event on a text area enclosed so many layers inside my component , here's my code

```
  it('onTextChange', () => {
const textArea = mount(<Summary {...props} />);
const event = { target: { value: 'sometext' } };
jest.resetAllMocks();

expect(textArea.find('textarea').simulate('change', event));
expect(props.onTextChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(props.onTextChange).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(event);
});
```

I get the following error

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

I'm really new to jest and enzyme so I'm really familiar with it, but this error is really confusing and I'm really sure where to go from here neither that I get what's the answer for the other issues mentioning the same problem.

Any other solution that would allow me to simulate an onChange event whilst using only jest and enzyme and baring in mind that I'll have to render the whole component not only the text area are more than welcome.

Comment: This typically means that `textArea.find('textarea')` returns no objects. How does your `Summary` component look like? What is the output of `console.log(textArea.debug())` in your test?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the text area component is not shown when I try debug, is there a way to make mount render all the DOM elements required ?

Comment: Well `mount` should do. How does your `Summary` component look like? Will you share some essential part of the code?